# I am cross-compiling MONO for a PPC32

Tags: garbage-collection, mono, autoconf, powerpc

I need to tell autoconf what the --host parameter is but I don't know the syntax or acceptable values.  I tried i386 and noticed it created a i386-libtool in the root directory.  Is there a list of acceptable host parameters (along with other parameters?)

My target is a ppc32 and I am using a cross compiler that runs on intel with linux ubuntu 22

Tried --host=i386 but got to the garbage collector part of the build and there was no makefile created so the build stopped.